# I'm getting a syntax error and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting an invalid syntax error in this line but i cant figure out why.
I know it has to do something with the >=, but i cant find my error.
Sorry if this is a stupid question.

```
 if +age+ >=18 print ("Wait a minute " + name + " ")
```

Comment: please share the error when you encounter one and ask about it

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the ':' for your if statement. Try:

```
if +age+ >=18:
    print ("Wait a minute " + name + " ")
```

Also some of your other code is weird. So, let me know if this still throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming variables called `age` and `name` exist, I would suggest:

```
if age >=18: 
    print ("Wait a minute " + name + " ")
```

Comment: +1 to this because putting the + operator on either side of the variable name is weird and seems to be the main syntax error that the author is referring to

Comment: I tried this but i got this error.         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/86a7635d17773755/main.py", line 22, in 
    if age >=18: print ("Wait a minute " + name + " ")
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: It sounds as if `age` is a string variable. Try `int(age) >= 18:`